# SQL Matching Time durations (fromDatetime- toDatetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, overlap

I have 2 tables

Table A

| ... | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 2021.01.01 7:15:00 | 2021.01.01 9:30:00 |

Table B

| ... | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 2021.01.01 6:10:00 | 2021.01.01 6:30:00 |
| ... | 2021.01.01 7:00:00 | 2021.01.01 7:32:00 |
| ... | 2021.01.01 7:45:00 | 2021.01.01 9:15:00 |

Starting from table A, I would like to have the data split according to the time in table B.
Where the times in table B would be the correct times intervals to use.

An example of what I mean
The result should be:

| ... | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 2021.01.01 7:15:00 (from A) | 2021.01.01 7:32:00 (from B) |
| ... | 2021.01.01 7:45:00 (from B) | 2021.01.01 9:15:00 (from B) |

```sql
create table #A (
    StartTime datetime
    , EndTime datetime
);

create table #B (
    StartTime datetime
    , EndTime datetime
);

insert into #A
select {ts'2021-01-01 07:15:00'}, {ts'2021-01-01 09:30:00'}

insert into #B
select {ts'2021-01-01 06:10:00'}, {ts'2021-01-01 06:30:00'}
insert into #B
select {ts'2021-01-01 07:00:00'}, {ts'2021-01-01 07:32:00'}
insert into #B
select {ts'2021-01-01 07:45:00'}, {ts'2021-01-01 09:15:00'}


Drop Table #A, #B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you join `B` with `A` where the two ranges overlap (i.e. some part of one range overlaps some part of the other range). Once you found the overlapping rows, clamp the start and end dates of `B`, if necessary:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN a.StartTime > b.StartTime THEN a.StartTime ELSE b.StartTime END AS s,
    CASE WHEN a.EndTime   < b.EndTime   THEN a.EndTime   ELSE b.EndTime   END AS e
FROM b
JOIN a ON a.EndTime > b.StartTime AND b.EndTime > a.StartTime
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b3a3e0104fb803caeefcccbbfcc55bad)

Answer (score 0):

I'd inner join on A including B and then use a row_number for ordering:

```
select 
     A.StartTime as OriginalStartTime
    ,A.EndTime as OriginalStartTime
    ,row_number() over (order by B.StartTime) as portion
    ,B.StartTime as PortionStartTime
    ,B.EndTime as PortionEndTime
from
    TableA as as
    inner join TableB as B on B.StartTime>=A.StartTime and B.EndTime<=A.EndTime
order by 3 asc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still does not provide the solution I was looking for, it does not create the 1st record:
``` lang-sql
select 
     TableA.StartTime as OriginalStartTime
    , TableA.EndTime as OriginalStartTime
    , row_number() over (order by TableB.StartTime) as portion
    , TableB.StartTime as PortionStartTime
    , TableB.EndTime as PortionEndTime
from
    #A as TableA
    inner join #B as TableB on TableB.StartTime>=TableA.StartTime and TableB.EndTime<=TableA.EndTime
order by 3 asc
```

Comment: Change the `join` accordingly