# Calculate the time period a certain field is overlapping in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently trying to figure out the overlapping time period between records. I already have a query that indicates if it is overlapping another field with 'yes' and 'no'. But I need to have the exact duration of the overlapping time period when the field has 'yes' as indication. Can someone help me with it?

Query:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 
        ([StartDateTime] BETWEEN (LAG([StartDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID])) 
                             AND (LAG([EndDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID]))) OR
        ([EndDateTime] BETWEEN (LAG([StartDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID])) 
                           AND (LAG([EndDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID]))) OR
        ([StartDateTime] < (LAG([StartDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID])) 
         AND [EndDateTime] > (LAG([EndDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID]))) OR
        ([StartDateTime] > (LAG([StartDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID])) 
         AND [EndDateTime] < (LAG([EndDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID])))
        THEN 'yes'
    WHEN (LAG([StartDateTime], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [aaID])) IS NULL
        THEN NULL
    ELSE 'no'
END AS [OverLapping with Previous]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: For the record: I can't just say if 'yes' then datediff, because of the fact that the starttime of the overlapping record can begin earlier than the starttime of the previous record..

Comment: Search "gaps and islands". And if you REALLY want to understand how to identify whether two time periods overlap, just get out some graph paper and draw periods on a timeline to actually "see" the logic you need. This is one case where playing around with a few sample periods visually really helps understand the logic.

Comment: In regards to your comment about 'datediff', why would that be a issue?

Comment: Hi @Bashton because the overlap can be when: starttime is greater than, less then or equal to. The same is applied to endtime

Comment: @SalmanA I would like to calculate the overlap with n  rows, so not just the previous. Because their could be 5 rows that has overlap in all sorts of combinations

Comment: OK, for the picture above, you need to compare start time with running max of end time until previous row; all data sorted by start time. That'll give you the yes/no. If you want to find which row overlaps what rows (e.g. 1 row overlaps 5 rows) then you need to use self join (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/69881846/87015). Deleting other comments.

Comment: Take a look at the pseudo code in the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag. I keep it bookmarked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this for the difference in days.

```
case when ([StartDateTime] >= (lag([StartDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])) and [EndDateTime] <= (lag([EndDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID]))) 
     Then DateDiff(day, [StartDateTime], [EndDateTime])
     when ([StartDateTime] <= (lag([StartDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])) and [EndDateTime] >= (lag([EndDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])))
     Then DateDiff(day, (lag([StartDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])), (lag([EndDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])))
     when ([StartDateTime] < (lag([StartDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])) and [EndDateTime] < (lag([EndDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID]))) And [EndDateTime] > (lag([StartDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID]))
     Then DateDiff(day, (lag([StartDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])), [EndDateTime])
     when ([StartDateTime] > (lag([StartDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])) and [EndDateTime] > (lag([EndDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID]))) And [StartDateTime] < (lag([EndDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID]))
     Then DateDiff(day, [StartDateTime], (lag([EndDateTime],1) over (order by [aaIDID])))
end as Diff
```

Comment: Hi @Anton Grig thanks for the answer. I needed the overlapping datediff in minutes, but that's just changing the day expression in minute. I tried it out and it seemed to work.

Comment: @SQLlearner123 You are welcome! I tried it too before I posted it. Could you mark the answer as accepted if it suits for you?